# Storing multiple objects in a file

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist, file-handling

I have a collection of objects in form of an ArrayList and I want to keep all of the objects into a file. At present I am storing the complete ArrayList into the file(of size 26,000) and I have experienced a latency of 80ms in reading it. Which way is better? Storing the complete ArrayList or the Array of Objects into the file?
P.S.: No of objects can be above millions in count.

Comment: In what format are you storing them? An arbitrary file format?

Answer (score 0):

I think saving `ArrayList<T>` to single binary file using `Serializable` is a best way unless your data file is up to 4 Gb.

In the other way you can do the serialization in multiple threads. If you'll go this way - it is possible to find `n` - optimal number of threads and array parts.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, Do you have any reference or documentation links so that I could see further into it?

Comment: Main bound is disk drive throughput. See java.io.FileOutputStream and its`native void writeBytes(byte b[], int off, int len)`. With an average HDD we have 100 Mb/s